# Is it possible to install circular avatar in place of axis text labels

Tags: charts, label, rgraph

I've got a requirement to install people's faces on the Y-Axis of a bar chart. Is it possible to install a custom image in place of the axis label?  Ideally the solution would enable border-radius, border-style, and image URL properties.

Bonus points if you can point me towards documentation for enabling image-axis-label click & mouseover events!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of using images as labels here:

https://www.rgraph.net/demos/bar-images-as-labels.html

But keep in mind that they're not DOM objects - ie you can't style them with CSS on add mouseover events to them (at least not in the standard way). You could add a mouseover using RGraph though.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Have you got a link to RGraph compatible image styling? I'm hoping to create similar to this CSS style: 
background: transparent url(/img.png) center center no-repeat;
border-radius: 8px

Comment: There's not much in the way of styling - you could use the coords (which are held in obj.coords[0] ) to draw a border around the image (use the ondraw event) but there's no styling (apart from what's listed on the docs page http://www.rgraph.net/docs/drawing-api-image.html ). I look at adding something like border-radius for the next version - but that could be some time away yet.

Comment: I'll also add that you can use CSS on the canvas tag itself - like this example does to add a background-color and a border-radius: http://www.rgraph.net/demos/line-black-and-purple.html

Comment: I've now added four properties to the drawing API image object: border [false], border.color [black], border.width [1] and border.radius [0]. Try them if you wish and get back to me about any bug(s) should you find one.

Comment: They'll be in the next beta BTW.